# up-casting a function to another of base class parameter

Tags: c++, casting, functor, upcasting

I want to up-cast a function whose parameter is of type `Sub` to another function type whose parameter is of type `Base`. (`Sub` extends `Base`)

```
std::function<void(Sub)> child_f = ...
std::function<void(Base)> base_f = static_cast<std::function<void(Base)>>(child_f);
```

The code above didn't work. Can anyone tell me what went wrong?

Comment: Can you explain the motivation behind the casting? what do you need to do with the function ?

Answer (score 2):

`std::function<void(Base)>` is incompatible with the signature `void(Sub)` because there is no conversion from `Base` to `Sub`.

The opposite is not true.  `std::function<void(Sub)>` is compatible with the signature `void(Base)` since a conversion exists to convert from `Sub` to `Base`.  That means the following *will* work:

```
std::function<void(Base)> base_f = someFunction;
std::function<void(Sub)> child_f = base_f;
```

Answer (score 0):

> The code above didn't work. Can anyone tell me what went wrong?

Your expectation that `std::function<void(Sub)>` can be cast to `std::function<void(Base)>` is ill-founded. They are two unrelated types despite the relationship between `Base` and `Sub`.

Take a much simpler case:

```
template <typename T> struct Empty {};

Empty<Sub> e1;
Empty<Base> e2 = static_cast<Empty<Base>>(e1); // Not going to work either
```

That's becase `Empty<Sub>` does not have a base class/derived class relationship with `Emtpy<Base>`.

Bottom line: You can't do what are attempting to do.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include `Sub : Base`, but the question still holds.